# Handling multiple entity relationships on a single entity in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have four JPA entities that are related. The relationship goes like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String personId;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "person")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    private String companyId;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "company")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    // private String parentId;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Area> area = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")     // hibernate forces me to use insertable = false, updatable = false
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")     // hibernate forces me to use insertable = false, updatable = false
    private Company company;
}

@Entity
public class Area {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
}
```

What is want to achieve is, when a person is being created, i want to be able to save the address of the person with person's id as `parent_id` in address table, similarly when a company is being created i want to be able to save the address of the company with company's id as `parent_id` in address table.

Now, hibernate forces me to add `insertable = false, updatable = false` on either `person` or `company` reference in Address entity, without which my spring boot app won't start. If i add it on person, i am able to save company with address through

```
company.getAddress().setCompany(company);
companyRepository.save(company);
```

Same way if i add it on company, i am able to save address for the person. But i am not able to save address for person and company both. How do i achieve this? I don't want to simply add separate columns for personId, companyId in address table which is redundant when i can use a single column to save the parent reference.

I also want to fetch address along with person or company through `findById` of respective repositories.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Having bidirectional associations in Hibernate usually brings some issues (what you found is one of the many). This is just a basic problem as maintaining the associations is not simple, so hibernate puts a some of restrictions. Do you need to navigate from an Address to a Company or Person? I often find that bidirectional associations are not needed, but are added 'just in case'.

Comment: I don't really need to navigate from Address to Company or Person. But i think that i'll come across same problem even if i use unidirectional mapping. Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: I did try the uni-directional mapping, and i can save everything by setting `address.parentId(person.getPersonId())`. But then when i do `findById(personId)` on `personRepository`, i get exception `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.nasdaq.entity.Address. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String`

Comment: You need to put the FK on the Person and Company classes. Otherwise hibernate cannot figure out that the FK could be to either Person or Company.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did. With this annotation in Person class: `@JoinColumn(name = "personId", referenceColumnName = "parentId", nullable = false)`. Similarly for Company class as well.